# Export multidimensional arrays to CSV and JSON using maatwebsite

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I have a question about exporting data.

I am using maatwebsite with laravel 5.4. I have an array of arrays like this:

```
array:8 [▼
  "company_id" => "2"
  "company_name" => "Test Company2"
  "survey_id" => "1"
  "survey_name" => "ELMAO"
  "customer_id" => "5"
  "customer_first_name" => "Lol"
  "customer_last_name" => "Kek"
  "questions" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
      "question_name" => "1"
      "question_title" => ""
      "response_text" => "2"
      "screenshot_url" => "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAeAAAAHvCAYAAACMggxAAAAgAElEQVR4XuydCZwdVZX/f/W2XpLOvq9kYwkh7BACjKCCrAEMmywqiqij4gAqOjoqo6OOOgoDKjgqyoCIiIp/GEH2fcdAyB5IyL4nvfdb6//5nXqv ▶"
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▼
      "question_name" => "7"
      "question_title" => "Keek!"
      "response_text" => "2"
      "screenshot_url" => "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAeAAAAHvCAYAAACMggxAAAAgAElEQVR4XuydB7hcZbX+3z3tlPRGeg+EQAhBSkKAK6ggUkIJTYqKIupV8Qooer1XRb3qVa/CRRFsKBdERFT8g4D03iEQ0kggIb2enH6mz/95156J ▶"
    ]
  ]
]
```

How can I export this data to a CSV file and as a JSON string also?

Answer (score 0):

When retrieving data from the eloquent model you have build in functions to set it to JSON. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9573700/5871725